# How to define an abbreviation

Tags: macros

I want to define an abbreviation, for example, `\newcommand{\pca}{Principal Component Analysis}`. It seems trivial, but I am unable to do it. Please see below the code snippet-

```
\documentclass{article}

% define an abbreviation
\newcommand{\pca}{Principal Component Analysis}

\begin{document}
\pca is an unsupervised, non-parametric statistical technique primarily in machine learning. The dimensionality reduction can be done using \pca.
\end{document}
```

Below is a screenshot of the generated output-

[image]

**It can be seen that there is no space between "analysis" and "is" as highlighted in the screenshot above.**

*Adding a space intentionally using `\pca~is` could be a workaround, but I believe there must be a better way. Please suggest.*

Comment: you can use `~` or `\ ` or {} ` to get the space. (`~` prevents line breaking)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thank you very much. `\pca{}` is working fine. But can't we omit parenthesis just like `\alpha`, `\beta`, `\gamma`, etc.?

Comment: it is the same with `\alpha` except that spaces are ignored in math, in math `$a b$` is the same as `$ab$` but in text you need the space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I understood. Thank you very much. The syntax `\pca{}` looks like passing no arguments to it, *(although the command `\pca` is already defined to take no arguments)*.

Comment: no it's a group, like `{\itshape this is italic} this not` `{}` don't always mean arguments in tex

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for explaining to me.